# Using OpenWeatherMap forecast API in PHP

Tags: php, json, api, openweathermap

I am trying to show the forecast for a city from openweathermap.
But my foreach show nothing. Whats wrong?

```
<?php
  $url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?zip=85080,de&lang=de&APPID=MYKEY";

  $contents = file_get_contents($url);
  $clima = json_decode($contents, true);

  foreach($clima as $data) {
    echo $data->list->main->temp_min;
  }
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to dump $clima and $data? If not, try that and see what they return

Comment: Iam getting an array, but i dont know how to show that in my foreach correctly echo $clima->list->main->temp_min;

Comment: i did this. Key is only not shown here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result from a `json_decode(string, true)` is an associative array.

```
<?php

  $url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?zip=85080,de&lang=de&APPID=MYKEY";

  $contents = file_get_contents($url);
  $clima = json_decode($contents, true);

  foreach($clima['list'] as $data) {
    echo $data['main']['temp_min'];
  }

?>
```

If you want to use object syntax, don't set associative to `true`.

```
$clima = json_decode($contents);

foreach($clima->list as $data) {
  echo $data->main->temp_min;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to do the same in while?

Comment: Looping over this using a `while` seems very strange. If you want to limit your results to a certain number, use `array_slice`. If you want to limit your results based on some other criteria, use an `if` and then `break` out of the `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

Lets try it...

```
<?php
    $city    = 'Dhaka';
    $country = 'BD';
    $url     = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=' . $city . ',' . $country . '&units=metric&cnt=7&lang=en&appid=c0c4a4b4047b97ebc5948ac9c48c0559';
    $json    = file_get_contents( $url );
    $data    = json_decode( $json, true );
    $data['city']['name'];
    // var_dump($data );
    
    foreach ( $data['list'] as $day => $value ) {
        echo 'Max temperature for day ' . $day
        . ' will be ' . $value['temp']['max'] . '<br />';
        echo '<img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' . $value['weather'][0]['icon'] . '.png"
                    class="weather-icon" />';
    
    }
```

Comment: It is helpful if you explain how your code works and why instead of just providing some code without context

Answer (score 0):

You used `json_decode` with parameter *associative* to true.

So **$data** is rather an array not an object.

Based on that [sample](https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=94040,us&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22) (similar to your url), you should access your values with [square bracket syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing) :

```
$data['main']['temp_min'];
```